# Javascript parse error - Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, parse-error

I have tried to create a custom JavaScript GTM variable after reading a tutorial.

But I just get the message that I have a parse error.

Error at line 43, character 5: Parse error. ')' expected

Not sure what's wrong here. Any ideas? thanks.

```
function countdown(endDate) {
  var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

  endDate = new Date(endDate).getTime();

  if (isNaN(endDate)) {
    return;
  }

  setInterval(calculate, 1000);

  function calculate() {
    var startDate = new Date();
    startDate = startDate.getTime();

    var timeRemaining = parseInt((endDate - startDate) / 1000);

    if (timeRemaining >= 0) {
      days = parseInt(timeRemaining / 86400);
      timeRemaining = (timeRemaining % 86400);

      hours = parseInt(timeRemaining / 3600);
      timeRemaining = (timeRemaining % 3600);

      minutes = parseInt(timeRemaining / 60);
      timeRemaining = (timeRemaining % 60);

      seconds = parseInt(timeRemaining);

      document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = parseInt(days, 10);
      document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = ("0" + hours).slice(-2);
      document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);
      document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
}

(function () { 
  countdown('09/06/2019 12:00:00 AM'); 
}());
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code excerpt don't have 43 lines (see error message), could you perhaps improve the question by pointing to the line that causes the problem?

Comment: That error often means your brackets are not properly balanced, but the code you posted has proper brackets. The problem is probably somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of a Custom Javascript variable in GTM is the following:

```
 function() {
   //your code
   return //your result;
 }
```

This is the reason, why you get an error message, when you try to save your code.

So you need to include only the core functionality, you want to achieve here. However, this type of variable should be used primarily to calculate and return a value, and not to manipulate the DOM.

What you need, is a Custom HTML tag, where the script should be included within a `script` tag:

```
<script>
function countdown(endDate) {
  //your countdown function
}

(function () { 
  countdown('09/06/2019 12:00:00 AM'); 
}());
</script>
```

You will also need a trigger, which launches this tag upon page load. Possibly, only after DOM or on Window Loaded, so that all elements are available, when your script runs.

Also please note, that `countdown` will be created in the global namespace, so you need to take care not to overwrite an other countdown function, or have it overwritten.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to make the changes you suggested.