# GTM custom java script "Error at line 13, character 5: Parse error. ')' expected"

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm made script that extracts offer id's in teh basket. In console it returns values as intended but when trying to run a preview in GTM it returns mentioned error.
Do you know how can I fix this script?

```
(function () {
    
  var cartItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr.cart-item')).map(function(item) { return item.querySelector('a'); });

  function mapId(a) {
      return a.href.split('products/')[1].split('?')[0]; 
  }

  var result = cartItems.map(mapId);
  
  return result;

})();
```

I tried adjusting the code but it didn't help

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the tag or variable? Can not reproduce this error

Comment: here is a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/KOXhJH4

Comment: didn't put this variable in any tag yet

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817173/javascript-parse-error-google-tag-manager